# Iterate through nested list data type in OCaml

Tags: list, recursion, ocaml

I'm trying to iterate through the `Sexp.t` data type, defined in the Jane Street [Sexplib module](https://dev.realworldocaml.org/data-serialization.html#scrollNav-1). I want to print out the data type in a way that shows its recursive structure for debugging. So far, this is what I have:

```ocaml
type sexp =
  | Atom of string
  | List of sexp list

(* pretty prints an sexp *)
let rec to_str (se : sexp) : string =
  match se with
  | Atom s -> s
  | List [] -> ""
  | List (hd :: tl) -> to_str hd ^ to_str (List tl)

let () =
  let se = List [Atom "a"; List [Atom "b"; Atom "c"]; Atom "d"; Atom "e"] in
  print_endline (to_str se)
```

The output is `abcde`, a flattened list. I'm hoping to print it out as something similar to:

```
List [Atom "a"; List [Atom "b"; Atom "c"]; Atom "d"; Atom "e"]
```

I've made a few attempts that got messy fast. I'm just not sure what the recursive case is supposed to look like. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't very efficient, but makes very few changes to your function, and should hopefully be easy to understand:

```
let rec to_str (se : sexp) : string =
  match se with
  | Atom s -> Printf.sprintf "Atom \"%s\"" s
  | List [] -> ""
  | List items ->
    let items = items |> List.map to_str |> String.concat "; " in
    Printf.sprintf "List [%s]" items
```

which prints

```
List [Atom "a"; List [Atom "b"; Atom "c"]; Atom "d"; Atom "e"]
```

It uses `Printf.sprintf` for convenience, but could still use plain string concatenation if you want to. A more efficient version could use `Format.fprintf` instead.

Comment: Thank you, very clean! It's for debugging so efficiency isn't too important, but I'll think about your approach/how to improve the running time.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @glennsl is great, but let's look at what your code is doing to see why it gives you the result you saw.

> ```
> let rec to_str (se : sexp) : string =
>   match se with
>   | Atom s -> s
>   | List [] -> ""
>   | List (hd :: tl) -> to_str hd ^ to_str (List tl)
> ```

You then evaluated `to_str se` where `se` is `List [Atom "a"; List [Atom "b"; Atom "c"]; Atom "d"; Atom "e"]`.

```
to_str (List [Atom "a"; List [Atom "b"; Atom "c"]; Atom "d"; Atom "e"])

to_str (Atom "a") ^ to_str (List [List [Atom "b"; Atom "c"]; Atom "d"; Atom "e"])

"a" ^ (to_str (List [Atom "b"; Atom "c"]) ^ to_str (List [Atom "d"; Atom "e"]))

"a" ^ (to_str (Atom "b") ^ to_str (List [Atom "c"]))
    ^ (to_str (Atom "d") ^ to_str (List [Atom "e"]))

"a" ^ ("b" ^ (to_str (Atom "c") ^ to_str (List [])))
    ^ ("d" ^ (to_str (Atom "e") ^ to_str (List [])))

"a" ^ ("b" ^ ("c" ^ ""))
    ^ ("d" ^ ("e" ^ ""))

"a" ^ ("b" ^ "c") ^ ("d" ^ "e")

"a" ^ "bc" ^ "de"

"abcde"
```